# How To Know Selected Radio Button in Codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, code-behind

I Have A grid view with 3 radio buttons. How Can I Know Which Radio Button Is Selected>

Code:

Comment: Well to tell you the truth I did not try anything I searched the net a lot and all the methods I found where using JavaScript and as I do not wish to use JavaScript I am in a sort of a dilemma :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please give a try

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridview.Rows)
{
    RadioButton radioBtn=new RadioButton();
    radioBtn=(RadioButton)row.findcontrol("YourRadiobuttonId");
    if(radioBtn.Checked)
    {
        // Your appropriate code here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridview.Rows)
{
RadioButton rbn=new RadioButton();
rbn=(RadioButton)row.findcontrol("YourRadiobuttonId");
if(rbn.Checked)
 {
    //Try your condition what u want
 }
}
```